# python tldextract.extract giving BadStatusLine: ''

Tags: python, tld

I'm getting `BadStatusLine: ''` error when using `tldextract.extract(url)`:

```
subdomain, domain, tld = tldextract.extract(url)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 194, in extract
    return TLD_EXTRACTOR(url)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 128, in __call__
    return self._extract(netloc)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 132, in _extract
    registered_domain, tld = self._get_tld_extractor().extract(netloc)
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 165, in _get_tld_extractor
    tlds = frozenset(tld for tld_source in tld_sources for tld in tld_source())
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 165, in <genexpr>
    tlds = frozenset(tld for tld_source in tld_sources for tld in tld_source())
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 204, in _PublicSuffixListSource
    page = _fetch_page('http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1')
  File "/usr/local/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tldextract/tldextract.py", line 198, in _fetch_page
    return unicode(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), 'utf-8')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1207, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1180, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1030, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 407, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 371, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to that mozilla.org URL in your stacktrace (http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1) being unavailable, and `tldextract` tries to update from that URL on first install. This live update can be disabled (see below), but the uncaught exception is a `tldextract` bug. It should only log the exception, and seamlessly fallback to package's bundled PSL.

This is **fixed in tldextract 1.2.1**, just published to [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tldextract/1.2.1). It switches to the [GitHub mirror of the PSL](https://raw.github.com/mozilla/mozilla-central/master/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat). So upgrading should workaround the uncaught exception.

Another release soon will avoid future uncaught exceptions when the e.g. GitHub PSL mirror is unavailable.

#### Turning off the default fetch

You can avoid this problem in the previous version by turning off the default on-first-install fetch. Construct your own `TLDExtract` callable with `fetch=False`. From [the docs](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/blob/1.2.1/README.md):

```
import tldextract
no_fetch_extract = tldextract.TLDExtract(fetch=False)
no_fetch_extract('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

The package is trying to download a public suffix list from a URL that currently does not work:

```
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1
```

This is due to a [DDOS attack on that URL](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=924785), Mozilla has blocked the URL for now.

This has [already been reported to the project](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/issues/42), and a [fix has been proposed](https://github.com/john-kurkowski/tldextract/pull/43) albeit that the latter only works if you already have a cached copy of the public suffix list.

In the meantime, use the [`publicsuffix` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/publicsuffix/) instead; it bundles the data in the package itself and does not require a URL request.

**Update**: Mozilla now host the file at https://publicsuffix.org/list/effective_tld_names.dat and any access to the MXR source repository *without a mxr.mozilla.org Referer header* redirects you to that new location.

Comment: Thanks @Martijn Pieters.  Doesn't look like publicsuffix returns tld, domain and subdomain though right?

Comment: @AJP: Indeed; `publicsuffix` *only* splits off the tld. All that `tldextract` does extra is use `.rsplit('.', 1)` on the remainder.

Comment: `tldextract` bundles the PSL as well, but, perhaps by poor design, by default _tries_ the live PSL update on first install. The default fetch can be turned off by constructing your own `TLDExtract` callable: `my_extractor = tldextract.TLDExtract(fetch=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1 not being served.

If you want to keep using tldextract to obtain the subdomain, domain, tld, a temporary solution is to use a cache, e.g. in `project/tldextractor/__init__.py`

```
import os 
import tldextract
TLD_CACHE_PATH = os.path.join(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'tldextract_cache')
tldextractor = tldextract.TLDExtract(cache_file=TLD_CACHE_PATH, fetch=False)
```

In `project/tldextractor/tldextract_cache`: https://gist.github.com/AJamesPhillips/6899560

then:

```
from .tldextractor import tldextractor
tldextractor('http://subdomain.domain.tld')
```